# In Tomcat 8, is there a way to load DLLs so they are available when reloading a WebApp?

Tags: java, dll, web-applications, tomcat8

I have a WebApplication (Java/Angular) and I am loading several 3rd party DLLs for optical character recognition and PDF manipulation.  I load them using the System.loadLibrary method and since the file are in the java.library.path, this works fine.  However when I redeploy the webApp, I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library [library name] already loaded in another classloader
```

I know why, because the WebApp class loaders are the last class loaders in the hierarchy and isolated from each other.  But why aren't those DLLs gc'ed when the app is replaced?
I know others have addressed this, but so far nothing has worked.  I've tried moving the files into Catalina_base\lib, I've tried unloading the DLLs through several ideas on the web ... So far nothing  seems to help.  Any ideas?

Comment: No answers yet.  Maybe this will help.  I am loading the DLL's following Tomcat docs in the /shared/lib and included it in my system path.  I also tried putting them in the /lib folder, with that in the system path.  In each case they are not listed in the WEB-INF/lib, which tells me they are loading based one of the other Tomcat classloaders.  I have also added the path to the catalina.properties shared loader.  I have also changed the loader Delegate="true" in the Context.xml and nothing changes.  The web app finds the libraries fine, until I reload the app and then I have to re-boot.

Comment: All I am trying to do is avoid re-booting everytime I deploy the WAR

Comment: OK, more information.  I found a DLL Loader and load the DLLs in a separate JAR running under the Tomcat/lib folder.  Messages say they are loading fine.  However I cannot get my application to recognize them.  I have even added a SHARED folder, like the ones older versions of Tomcat had, but no change.  The DLLs load, but if I try and reload them in the app (System.loadLibrary( . . .) I get the original error message.  When I try and access their methods I get an unsatisfied link message tied to one of my local methods.